# Need a batch file to remove first three lines and empty lines in Notepad++

Tags: batch-file, notepad++

I need a batch file to remove first three lines and remove empty lines.

**Input:**

```
Saved from Clipdiary 08 January 2018 13:13:11



=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

AAAAAAA


BBBBBBB


CCCCCCC


DDDDDDD


EEEEEEE
```

**Like this:**

```
AAAAAAA
BBBBBBB
CCCCCCC
DDDDDDD
EEEEEEE
```

Current code, *(from comments)*:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do ( more +3 "%%~fi">>temp del "%%~fi" ren temp "%%~nxi" )
```

Comment: Have you tried anyting? And batch is not related to notepad++ in anyway

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this @echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
more +3 "%%~fi">>temp
del "%%~fi"
ren temp "%%~nxi"

)

Comment: I've fixed the formatting and edited  your code into your question. I've included an empty line in the data, but it was not possible to determine what your actual data was. Please edit-in some realistic data by using cut-and-paste. Select and use `{}` to format (indents each line 4 spaces)

Comment: I couldn't fix the output which i required.... am new to this...

Comment: `more +3 "%%~fi">>temp`, `del "%%~fi"` & `ren temp "%%~nxi"` are three different commands, either place each on a separate line or join them on that one line with ampersands.

Comment: Also in the latest Edit, `=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=` doesn't exist in the first three line so should also be in the `Like this:` version. To properly format your file content, copy it into the question, select it and press the button which looks like this, **`[{}]`**.

Answer (score 0):

`for /f` ignores empty lines. Generally, this is a flaw, but in your case it's exactly, what you need. Also no need for `more` as `for` also has a `skip` option.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  >temp (for /f "usebackq skip=3 delims=" %%a in ("%%i") do echo %%a)
  move /y temp "%%i" 
)
```